# Unable to find the element error in selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium

As per the requirement,

A dynamic web table needs to be filled from Excel sheet using selenium.

The web table is dynamic. And for each row in the excel sheet a new row has to be added in the web table

ID of a web element looks like this: `asr_100_ct100_ikview_ct155_view`

The next element's​ I'd looks like

`asr_100_ct100_ikview_ct156_view`

So, here I have done string concatenation like

```
Int j=155;

Driver.find element (by.id("asr_100_ct100_ikview_ct" +j+ "_view";

J++.
```

The above code is in for loop.

For each row in the excel sheet, a new webelement has to be found and data should be sent.

> Error: unable to find the element with Id
>   ==asr_100_ct100_ikview_ct155_view

Comment: Please be specific. I am not clear with your Question.

Comment: The problem here is string concatenation is not working fine. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you provide us with the HTML part?

Comment: @Sai Incase your Question is still unanswered can you please provide more info as: 1. What do you mean by `For each row in the excel sheet`? 2. What is the role of excel sheet data in this? 3. Can you share the relevant HTML DOM please?

Comment: @ dev, the steps needs to be executed are 1. Open a webpage, 2. There would be no table in the webpage Initially 3. There is a plus + sign on the webpage, upon clicking on + a new row will be added 4. The content to be filled into the webpage is available in Excel sheet. 5. For each row in Excel sheet, the + should be clicked.

Comment: @ dev 6. Suppose there are two rows to be added , the code is working fine to add 2 rows in the web table.7. each row has 4 td elements. 8.all these elements have unique ids. 9. Let us suppose a cell in first row is having a id as ct100_view_90_view 10. Cell in second row ID would be cr100_view_91_view.

Answer (score 1):

As this below code is working for me when i am concating the integer with string.

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int i = 100;
String s = "Hello, I am";
for(i=100;i<105;i++){
    System.out.println(s+ i +"Test");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please confirm if this is what you said: string s= integer.tostring(j).                                      Driver.findelement(by.id("asr_100_ct100_ikview_ct" +j+ "_view".   I am just wondering if the string concatenation what I am doing is correct syntax. Can you please suggest

Comment: No, I am not clear with your program. But As per the understanding of mine, I am giving you one example. public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int i = 100;
 String s = "Hello, I am";
 for(i=100;i<105;i++){
  System.out.println(s+ i +"Test");
 }
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Use xpath for find element.

```
//*[starts-with('id', 'asr_100_ct100_ikview_ct15')]
```

Comment: We must try to add a few words about your Solution along with the code while answering to the OP. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try xpath instead of id!

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\*[starts-with(@id,'asr_100')] 
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream("path");
XSSFWorkbook b= new XSSFWorkbook(fis); //make sure that it is .xlsx file
XSSFSheet sheet= b.getSheet("sheet name");
WebElement elem= driver.findElement(By.id("id of the whole table"));
List<WebElement> list= elem.findElements(By.xpath(//*[starts-with(@id,'tr id'));

int rows= sheet.getLastRowNum();
for(int i=0; i<rows;i++) {
    Row row= sheet.getRow(i);
    for(int j=0;j<row.getLastCellNum();j++) {
        for(WebElement e: list) 
                List<WebElement> tr= e.findElements(By.xpath(//*[starts-
                                   with(@id,'td id'))
                    for(WebElement d: tr)
                     d.sendKeys("data");
    }
}
```

if the element is a table, you have many rows and columns, you need to get data from every cell! 
first of all, you need to get that file from which you are reading!

//i'm sorry if I'm wrong
//please correct me if i'm wrong, i'm beginner in coding!